# How to set referrer to HtmlWeb in HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I want to assign a dynamic (meaning the referrer changes according to the request URL.

I cannot find a `Referrer` or `Headers` property. All I can see is `PreRequest`, to which I can add a handler. Is there any other way to pass a referrer to the handler without using a global variable?

```
   void SomeMethod()
   {
     ....
      var referrer = "some URL";
      //web.Referrer = referrer;  Ideal way, but not possible
      web.PreRequest += OnPreRequest;
      ....
   }

    bool OnPreRequest(HttpWebRequest req)
    {
        req.Referer = ??; //how to know the referrer address here?
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any other way to pass a referrer to the handler without using a global variable?

You can use *captured variables*. See, for ex, this link ["Understanding Variable Capturing in C#"](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/matt/2008/03/01/understanding-variable-capturing-in-c/) or this [Closures and Captured Variable C#](http://geekswithblogs.net/rajeevr/archive/2012/02/26/closures-and-captured-variable.aspx)

Now you can do

```
void SomeMethod()
{
    var referrer = "some URL";
    web.PreRequest += (req){
        req.Referer = referrer;
        return false;
    };
}
```

Some notes:

> **What are closures?**
>
> Closures are function which can be stored in a variable, passed around as parameter and refer to the variables visible at the time they are defined.
>
> **Captured Variable**
>
> Outer variable referenced by the closure is called captured variable